# VBA Outlook WordEditor and .Display method

Tags: vba, outlook

I've done reasonable "Googling" and could not find the answers for my problem.

I have the following two subroutines.  The two are are exactly the same, except the first one has "ForwardMailItem.Display", and the second one does not.  The result is the draft emails produced by the first one contains the inserted text "testing here" while those produced by the second one do not contain the inserted text.  I have a couple of questions and hope someone can help me.  1) How can I successfully insert new text in my forwarded emails without using the .Display method because the .InsertBefore by itself does not seem to do the trick?  2) What special things does .Display do in my case besides visually showing the item?

```
Sub TestInsertBeforeWithDisplay()

    Dim NewMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ForwardMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    For Each NewMailItem In Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
        Set ForwardMailItem = NewMailItem.FORWARD
        ForwardMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Characters(1).InsertBefore "testing here"
        ForwardMailItem.Display
        ForwardMailItem.Close olSave
    Next NewMailItem

End Sub

Sub TestInsertBeforeWithoutDisplay()

    Dim NewMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ForwardMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    For Each NewMailItem In Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
        Set ForwardMailItem = NewMailItem.FORWARD
        ForwardMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Characters(1).InsertBefore "testing here"
        ForwardMailItem.Close olSave
    Next NewMailItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I don't code Outlook too often, but I think the answer is that you have to close and save the ActiveInspector:

```
Sub TestInsertBeforeWithDisplay()
Dim NewMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ForwardMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ActInsp As Outlook.Inspector

For Each NewMailItem In Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
    Set ForwardMailItem = NewMailItem.Forward
    Set ActInsp = ForwardMailItem.GetInspector
    With ActInsp
        .WordEditor.Characters(1).InsertBefore "testing here"
        .Close (olSave)
    End With
    ForwardMailItem.Close olSave
Next NewMailItem
End Sub
```

I was able to duplicate your problem and the code above fixed it. I'm not sure if it's still necessary to save `ForwardMailItem`.